# NodeJS Extracting input value from url

Tags: node.js, extract, cheerio

I have html stored in a var

```
var html = "<div class="RiP" style="text-align: left;"><div class="clr"></div><input name="extraMP" value="999" type="hidden"><div class="txta dropError">Slide to activate</div><div class="bgSlider"><div class="Slider ui-draggable"></div></div><div class="clr"></div><input name="randomValue" value="randomValue2" type="hidden"></div>"
```

I want to extract "randomValue" and "randomValue2".

Maybe I should use cheerio? I tried with it but I had hard time managing to do it.

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 1):

If cheerio is hard for you - you could use regular expression to get the values.
For easily access you could provide class attribute for the `<input>` like:

```
<input class="className" name="randomValue" value="randomValue2" type="hidden">
```

your regexp will be:

```
const match = html.match(/<input\s*class="className"\s*name="(.+?)"\s*value="(.+?)"/m)
match[1] // randomValue
match[2] // randomValue2
```

With cheerio it will be:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const html = `<div class="RiP" style="text-align: left;"><div class="clr"></div><input name="extraMP" value="999" type="hidden"><div class="txta dropError">Slide to activate</div><div class="bgSlider"><div class="Slider ui-draggable"></div></div><div class="clr"></div><input class="myClass" name="randomValue" value="randomValue2" type="hidden"></div>`

const $ = cheerio.load(html);

$('.myClass').val(); // randomValue2
$('.myClass').attr('name'); // randomValue
```

Comment: [Don't use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Answer (score 0):

What you might do using [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) is to find the last input inside the `RiP` class and get the name and value attribute:

```
var html = `<div class="RiP" style="text-align: left;"><div class="clr"></div><input name="extraMP" value="999" type="hidden"><div class="txta dropError">Slide to activate</div><div class="bgSlider"><div class="Slider ui-draggable"></div></div><div class="clr"></div><input name="randomValue" value="randomValue2" type="hidden"></div>`;

const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const $ = cheerio.load(html);

let input = $('.RiP input').last();
console.log(input.attr('name'));
console.log(input.val());
```

Result:

```
randomValue
randomValue2
```

Note that it is not advisable to [parse html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)